# sunspot solr: What is the functional difference between path and solr_home?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

I was wondering if somebody can teach me the functional differences between *path* and *solr_home*. What kind of paths can they take (I know *path* cannot take filesystem path as parameters).

My current production configuration is:

```
port: 8080
path: /solr/
solr_home: /usr/share/apache-solr-3.3.0/solr/
```

I was under the impression that the index info is stored in my rails app /solr/ directory and that with every cap deploy they will be erased, but they are not so where are my solr index files stored? And what does that solr_home path do?

Please somebody clear my doubts.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solr home directory is supposed to contain your solr instance. It has a structure like this:

```
solr_home  
   |_  solr.xml (optional: multiple core configuration etc.)  
   |_  conf (directory containing the solr configuration)  
         |_  solrconfig.xml  
         |_  schema.xml  
   |_  data (default location for the index)
```

If you specified just the solr home without any additinal configuration you should find your index inside the solr_home/data directory.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you need some more information.

Comment: Hi @javanna, that explanation is certainly a clarification for me. So does sunspot read from my filesystem path? So in my case what is the difference between path and solr_home? I appreciate your answer...

Comment: @dryHumpingJava glad the answer is useful. I guess path is the location where the Solr webapp is installed, which is usually different from the location where you put your solr instance (solr_home).

Comment: Thanks - this helped me find where to put solr.xml (I was putting it in conf). I was configuring multi-cores in Sunspot and am using path to specify the core to use (path: /solr/core1).

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb, path is the location of the Solr servlet. solr_home is the location to where Sunspot::Rails expects to have config, data and pids directories. Note that there is also a thing called data_path, location of where to store and access your solr index.